# How to get a CDN to work for Staging and Production ENVs, using CloudFront, Rails, Jammit

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, amazon-s3, amazon-cloudfront, jammit

I just hooked Amazon's CLoudfront CDN up to our app.

In the staging and production.rb file, in rails all it took was:

```
  config.action_controller.asset_host = Proc.new { |source, request|
    if request.ssl?
      "https://cfIDhere.cloudfront.net"
    else
      # Pick a random CDN
      "http://cdn0#{source.hash % 4}.mysite.com"  
    end
  }
```

The challenge now is that both production and staging envs both call this:

```
http://cdn02.mysite.com/assets/application.js
```

That's going to create so crazy issues. What's the best way to handle making the CDN work for both Prod and Staging?

I'd love to be able to do something like this:

```
http://cdn02.mysite.com/assets/production/application.js
http://cdn02.mysite.com/assets/staging/application.js
```

Anyone have any experience with this? Thanks

Comment: what if you just did: `"http://cdn0#{source.hash % 4}.mysite.com/#{Rails.env}"` or `"http://#{Rails.env}.cdn0#{source.hash % 4}.mysite.com"`?  Otherwise you'd have to dig into the core `javascript_include_tag`-and-related code to customize the path.

Comment: I ended up doing that. Problem I found was that it breaks the CSS. If the css has an image like so url(/images...) that is now invalid... Ideas?

Answer (score 1):

I would segregate your CDNs by environment. So CDN{\d\d} would be production, then app-stage-cdn{\d\d} would be staging.